# Is custom communication with OBU inside a truck using microwave DRSC technology possible?

Tags: tracking-devices

Each truck in the Czech Republic must have an OBU - on board unit - installed:

https://www.mytocz.eu/en/obu/function-and-description

The OBU is using EasyGO + industrial standard and has

> the microwave DRSC technology for short-distance communication (serves
>   for checking of toll payers within the toll collection enforcement
>   process).

Is it possible to find a device (kind of custom toll gate) that would get the hardware ID of the OBU device entering our premises using [DRSC short-distance communication](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/sf11325.html)? Or is it encrypted and impossible?